# Jupyter notebook kernel dies while training model, Anaconda, Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I am using Anaconda distribution on Ubuntu. Training model using Tensoflow with multiple epochs. While training the model the computer memory is gradually completely consumed invcluding the main memory and the Swap. After that model training grinds to a halt and kernel dies after some time. In addition, I get the following error messages in the terminal window:

`...   QProcessPrivate::createPipe: Cannot create pipe 0x5571f6301100: Too many open files Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 459, in _conda_info_processed processed_info = self._process_conda_info(info) File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/api/anaconda_api.py", line 570, in _process_conda_info processed_info = info.copy() AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'copy'   ...`

Is this expected on Ubuntu? Is there a problem with Anaconda installation? How would you recommend fixing this memory problem? Is the error message related to the memory problem?

Comment: Depends on how much memory (RAM) you have and what model you are training. Most modern Deep ML models expect upward of 8 GB of RAM during training.

Comment: I have a rather modest amount of RAM equal to 8 GB. Also, 2 GB Swap. It does OK for the first pass through all epochs of my model with ~ 5000 parameters. When I do another training run it gets filled before the end of it. I am curious if this is expected/normall issue for Ubuntu or if I have some problems with the software setup?

Comment: In my limited experience, this is not a problem with Ubuntu. Try to free up some unused tensors/matrices after the first run. Can't tell you exact solution without looking at some code. The error you have shared simply tells us that system is running out of memory.

Comment: Thank you, @anurag. I thought so, but it is good to get other peoples opinion.

Comment: I think your question is missing crucial details related to your particular task. What are you training ? How ? You may want to add those details.